# Ionic3 - QR scanning - quality?

Tags: ionic2, ionic3, qr-code

Last weeks I built a Progressive Web App using Html/JS. I found several (free) libraries for scanning QR codes. The result of the QR-scanning was not very good. In many cases, no auto-focus was done by the video camera.

Can Ionic use the video camera very well to scan (any) QR-codes?

Does Ionic use the native (like) access to the video camera?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way of proving something is to build it ;-) Would an Ionic app have better QR scanning?

Today I created my first Ionic3 app. I used this [nice example](https://www.djamware.com/post/59bb219f80aca768e4d2b13e/example-of-ionic-3-angular-4-cordova-barcode-and-qr-code-scanner).

The difference in QR scanning quality was far more than I expected:

- After trying many (free) Javascript examples on the web, the quality was not very good. Alas.
- The solution of the Ionic/Cordova example on Android was **SUPERB**!

Ionic generates a native app (either for IoS or Android). It will use the native functionality of the video camera for scanning the QR.